# How to access the elements of a subclass for hovering purposes

Tags: html, css, colors, hover, navigationbar

I cant seem to access a subclass no matter what css i use to access the html element.

here is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Richazon</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <p>101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101
    101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101101011010110101</p>



</body>
</html>
```

i have managed to use this css

```
.navbar {
    background-color: blue;

}
```

to change the background to blue.
but when i use the same logic i.e. below css

```
.navbar  .nav:hover a{
    color: green;
}
```

full css below:

```
p { 
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: blue;

}

.navbar .nav a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

it will not change the text colour to green on hover.

Comment: `colour` should be `color`. Just that :) [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/atvm3ac4/).

Comment: see below @imgonzalves